# Unable to parse grokpattern for below log in opensearch

Tags: json, parsing

I am trying to parse the below log using Grok pattern, Grok pattern is parsing in grokdebugger but it is not able to parse in open search. Please find the log attached

{"level":"info","msg":"method:offlineActivate,name: SHAMPOO, customernumber:ASA76,ordernumber:0BLhf0,type:online","time":"2023-07-05T13:14:55Z"}

Could you please help with the grokpattern

I have written a Grok pattern to parse the log. Grok pattern is parsing in grokdebugger but it is not able to parse in open search. So, I want to find how an actual Grok pattern looks like for this one.